# Swipe gesture in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I would like to add swipe gesture to UINavigationBar. It is possible? As in figure.

[image: example]

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:getsure];

Comment: `UISwipeGestureRecognizer *barSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(barSwipeAction:)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:barSwipe];` It doesnt work for me. Method `barSwipeAction` is not called.

Comment: That navigation bar is from Navigationcontroller right ? or you added the navigation bar to your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it adding custom view into the navigation bar. After adding custom view into the navigation bar add gesture recognisers to it and change x-axis accordingly. Here is some useful resources about how to add custom or built-in view into the navigation bar. [add segmented control to navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813563/add-segmented-control-to-navigation-bar-and-keep-title-with-buttons)

Custom segmented view framework : [UIScrollSlidingPage](https://github.com/TomThorpe/UIScrollSlidingPages)